# Install hostmanager vagrant plugin - Unable to use symlinks on Windows

Tags: windows, plugins, vagrant, installation, symlink

I'm trying to write Vagrantfile with hostmanager plugin on **Windows 10** but have a problem. After plugin install got warning like below and finally 'hostmanager' could not be found:

```
λ vagrant plugin install hostmanager
Installing the 'hostmanager' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching: rubyhacks-0.1.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: hostmanager-1.2.2.gem (100%)
WARNING:  Unable to use symlinks on Windows, installing wrapper
Installed the plugin 'hostmanager (1.2.2)'!

λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'foo' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The 'hostmanager' provisioner could not be found.

Vagrant:
* Unknown configuration section 'hostmanager'.
```

How to solve this symlinks problem?

Answer (score 14):

type

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager
```

and it will be work fine

Answer (score 0):

Check if the '**hostmanager**' plugin is installed: Run the following command to list the installed Vagrant plugins:

> vagrant plugin list

If the **hostmanager** plugin is not listed, you may need to install it. You can install it with the following command:

> vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager